# How to query a loaded module by name?

Tags: linux

I am coding a program which needs making sure if the kernel has loaded the expected module before proceeding to run. What i need is some apis/systemcalls that provide functionalities for me to look up kernel  for the existence of my expected module by its name.I am looking forward your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read `/proc/modules`.

I just did a `strace lsmod` and it does the same thing.